# Массив в Java решать через методы

Tags: java

Надо найти минимальный элемент одномерного массива и затем надо удалить элементы массива до min.Как это сделать?

Comment: Сделать просто: найти минимальный элемент и удалить нужные элементы. В чем загвоздка?

Comment: Нужно загадать желание на stackoverflow и ждать.

Answer (score 2):

В связи с тем, что не совсем понятно, что означает фраза "надо удалить элементы массива", я продемонстрирую сортировку, а дальше вы уже сделаете необходимые манипуляции. Самый простой вариант - это `Arrays.sort(arr);` Немного разберемся, `arr` - это как раз массив, который желаете отсортировать. Подробнее можно почитать и посмотреть примеры [здесь](http://espressocode.top/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/).

Здесь мы ищем максимальный и минимальный эл-нт массива:

```
double[] array = { 0.22, 0.4, 0.92, 1.5, 1.99, 4.5 };
int indexOfMax = 0;
int indexOfMin = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > array[indexOfMax])
    {
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
    else if (array[i] < array[indexOfMin])
    {
        indexOfMin = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(indexOfMax + " " + indexOfMin);
```

Выбирайте какой варинт удобнее и дорабатывайте.